# Error while instaling Drupal 7

Tags: mysql, drupal, installation, drupal-7

I know that many people get the same kind of error when they try to install Drupal 7. But after trying out the solutions that I read about, I still didn't manage to install Drupal properly.

After installing 27 modules (of 28) I get the following message:

```
An AJAX HTTP error occurred. 
HTTP Result Code: 500 Debugging information follows.
Path: `http://localhost/drupal/install.php?profile=standard&locale=en&id=1&op=do`
StatusText: Service unavailable (with message) 
ResponseText: PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: 
SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} 
  WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => menu_rebuild ) 
    in lock_may_be_available() 
(line 167 of C:\wamp\www\drupal\includes\lock.inc).Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.PDOException: 
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: 
DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; 
Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 802228002541876118e8773.14607894 ) 
 in lock_release_all() 
(line 269 of C:\wamp\www\drupal\includes\lock.inc).
Uncaught exception thrown in session handler.PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: 
General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away: 
SELECT 1 AS expression FROM {sessions} sessions 
WHERE ( (sid = :db_condition_placeholder_0) AND 
 (ssid = :db_condition_placeholder_1) ); 
Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => ZLNqcOjZv5_OY8Y_fNwE0Il6hHmlJCLVL9qK5XUBTIo 
        [:db_condition_placeholder_1] => ) in _drupal_session_write() 
(line 209 of C:\wamp\www\drupal\includes\session.inc).'
```

When I restart WAMP server after it stopped, I can install Drupal anyway, but then it is not working properly.

- I have raised the number of the max_allowed_packet to various high amounts.
- I have raised other numbers in my my.ini.
- I have installed WAMP anew.
- Each time I try anew, I delete Drupal, my databank and my history in Chrome.
- My PHP version is 5.5.12
- I work in Windows 8
- I work on my localhost.

What else can I try?

---

I tried to increase the numbers in my.ini and php.ini, but that didn't help. I drop my database after each error.

I have a new idea myself:

Could it have something to do with my settings.php?

Before I start I set: `$update_free_access = FALSE;` to `TRUE` (as administrator in Notepad++). After I close the file I reopen it to check whether it has really changed. After I get the error I reopen the `settings.php` file and it says `$update_free_access = FALSE` again. But I did not change it back myself.

Could this be the source of my problem? How can I avoid this?

And should I do something with this in the same file?

```
'pdo' => array( * PDO::ATTR_TIMEOUT => 5,
```

Is there something else I should change in the `settings.php`?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not enough MySQL memory! Increasing MySQL memory might solve this issue (my.conf).

See here: https://www.drupal.org/node/1014172

Answer (score 0):

Try to change it in your php.ini:

```
max_allowed_packet=100M
```

I think it fixes your problem. Don't forget to restart wamp.
Regards.

Comment: Do you mean my my.ini? Because in my php.ini I cannot find a 'max_allowed_packet' I did change it in my my.ini and that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I think first time you tried installing Drupal, it must have met some unexpected termination. The above error also comes when all the tables and variables at install time are not configured properly.

I suggest to **drop** your database and attempt a fresh install again. Also, do ensure your installation is not timing out.

Answer (score 0):

RE: *I have raised other numbers in my my.ini.*

If you are using the WAMPServer 64bit install, please check that the my.ini file contains this section header [wampmysqld64]

i.e.

Replace [wampmysqld] with [wampmysqld64]

This section name should match the service name that MySQL is run under which in the 64bit install of WAMPServer is wampmysqld64. Unfortunately the 2.5 (64bit) release has this error in it.

Comment: well now its actually having an effect on your MySQL you need to check what you have changed

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help. I there something I'm missing?
I started anew: 
- I installed WAMP
- I downloaded Drupal 7.31.zip
- I copied the folder to www and unpacked it there
- I copied settings.default.php and named it settings.php and made both files writable.
- I made a database in myadminphp
- I opened localhost/drupal and started the installation.

The error always comes at the last moment of installing all modules and it is the same error each time.

I noticed that the word 'cache' is not in the my.ini. Is that correct?

What can I do?

Comment: Oh, I forgot, I also increased the max_allowed_packet to 256M. I found that both under the [wampmysqld64] and the [mysqldump]. So I raised both numbers.

Comment: But why did you do that? What made you think that was a solution to what problem

Comment: In all forums where they discuss this problems they always say: increase your 'max_allowed_packet'. For example Mario Araque above. Or am I misunderstanding something completely?

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your environment matches [System requirements](https://www.drupal.org/requirements) for Drupal.

> ```
> Drupal 7:
> MySQL 5.0.15/MariaDB 5.1.44/Percona Server 5.1.70 or higher with PDO,
> PostgreSQL 8.3 or higher with PDO,
> SQLite 3.3.7 or higher
> ```

and [database requirements](https://www.drupal.org/requirements/database) which says:

> It may be necessary to set the system variable `max_allowed_packet` to at least `16M`. Some inexpensive hosting plans set this value too low (the MySQL default is only `1M`). In that case, you may need to choose a better hosting plan.

So basically you need to edit your `my.cnf` (e.g. `~/.my.cnf`) and set or increase the value of `max_allowed_packet` your under `[mysqld]` section, e.g.

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=64M
```

If it's still failing, don't hesitate to increase it further more like `256M` in case when Drupal is in need of parsing huge amount of data.

See: [B.5.2.9 MySQL server has gone away](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html) for more detailed information.